# Create Facebook access token without logging in

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I want to receive the public posts of a defined facebook page in my app. I already integrated the FacebookSDK and created a new app in the Facebook developer console. My Request looks like this:

```
new Request(
                null,
                "/176063032413299/feed",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        tv.setText(response.getRawResponse());
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

The server answers, that I need an acceess token. But I don't want my users to be logged in, when they use my app. So is there an option to get an access token without being logged in? I only want to read public data. I am not interested in publishing or reading private posts.

If I use the app access token like this, it still does not work:

```
new Request(
                null,
                "/176063032413299/feed?access_token=xxx",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        tv.setText(response.getRawResponse());
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

I get the response:
"Invalid OAuth access token signature"

Comment: i believe no such way to do like this. You should read more about how Facebook authentication works

Comment: I read the documentation and I found several similar questions on Stackoverflow. All I know is, that this SHOULD work. But nether Facebook either someone else can provide a working code snippet or example app. Furthermore I used apps that display posts from several walls without asking me to log in.

Answer (score 2):

Even for public posts, you have to authorize the user in order to get access. Either with `read_stream` to get ALL posts or with `user_status` to get the posts of the user only.

read_stream will most likely not get approved by Facebook though, see this document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

Keep in mind that "public" does not mean you can grab it without user authorization. Apps can´t just scrape what they want - scraping is not allowed anyway: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Also, of course you can´t create a User Token (which is what you need) without user interaction (login and authorization). Detailed information about Access Tokens can be found in the following links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Btw, the docs mention that "Any valid access token is required to view public links." - So you may be able to get links only.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed

For debugging Access Tokens, use the Facebook Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

**Edit: I just realized that you just want to grab the public feed of a Facebook Page, not a User Profile. For that, you can just use an App Access Token. It´s never expiring and easy to create: `App-ID|App-Secret`. Check out the docs for more information. Keep in mind that you would need to use a User Token or Page Token if the Page is restricted by age or country.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am wondering how other apps solve this issue.

Comment: what other apps? also keep in mind that a lot of things are not possible anymore with v2.0, and apps using v1.0 will stop working after april 2015.

Comment: For example the Borussia Dortmund app just released an update. You can see the Facebook posts of all their players inside the app, without logging in to Facebook.

Comment: see the edit of my answer. for pages, you can just use an app access token.

Comment: jep, that is exactly what I was asking for. See my second code snippet with the Request and the error I get from the server.

Comment: looks like your access token is wrong. try to debug it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: no error there, seems to be a valid app access token! so something in my request has to be wrong. But I copied that snippet from the api docs...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68396/discussion-between-jensjensen-and-luschn).

Comment: works fine for me, test it in the browser directly: https://graph.facebook.com/176063032413299/feed?access_token=app-id|app-secret - i get all the entries without any problem.

Comment: Yeah in my browser it works. Just tested this last night. That's the reason why I finally came here to find some help ;)

Comment: ok, then maybe try removing the leading slash in the api call? and please post a link to the tutorial where you copied your code from, that would help a lot.

Comment: I have copied the Request code snippet from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed and just added the access token at the end. Without the leading slash I still get the same error.

Comment: I have the strange feeling this OAuthException is caused by the Apps configuartion in the Facebook dev console. But I have entered a debug keyhash and the facebook app id is included in my apps manifest.

Comment: or could this be caused by an encoding problem because of a pipe character in the url?

Comment: can you try without an access token and just "/176063032413299"? it should get you the page details and you don´t need a token for that.

Comment: Server answers "An access token is required to request this resource"

Comment: is that page restricted by age or location? see my answer if yes.

Comment: No, this is Leo Messis official page. I get the same error with every other page id.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed/

The permissions needed to be able to request `/{page_id}/feed`:

> - An access token is required to view publicly shared posts.
> - A user access token is required to retrieve posts visible to that person.
> - A page access token is required to retrieve any other posts.

Meaning you could generate a long-living Page Access Token to be able to retrieve the public Page Posts. As you won't want to store an expiring Access Token in your App, you'll have to create a backend web service to proxy the requests between the Graph API and your app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extendingpagetokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#refreshtokens

You should also be able to use an App Access Token, which is valid indefinitely.

Comment: you can´t refresh access tokens with a backend task. if that would be possible, the whole point of short living access tokens would be void, because you could just refresh it automatically. but extended page tokens are valid forever anyway.

Comment: Since v2.0 extended page access tokens are valid for 60 days as well imho.

Comment: really? i can´t find that anywhere in the changelog, and i am using extended page tokens since month without the need to refresh...even in v2.0 apps...

Comment: It's not documented... In my tests this was the behavior I got with v2.0 apps

Comment: ok, that could be a bug. or did you read something about this anywhere?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'll try to verify this again. Maybe this was a bug as you said, and was solved in the meantime.

Comment: I just verified that the long-lived Page Access Tokens now also never expire... Strange, but I'm glad it works

Answer (score -1):

Use [client token.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens?locale=en_GB)

You could also generate and sign your own personal token but you don't want to distribute that.