# How to get facebook fan page feed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get fan page news/feeds without user login and without access token. in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836175/create-facebook-access-token-without-logging-in) question I found that you don't need any access token. if you have App-ID and App-Secret. This solution works on browser but doesn't on Android app. 
Here is my code sample:

```
        new GraphRequest(null,
            "https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}/feed?access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("Facebook_feed", response.toString());
                }
            }).executeAsync();
```

Here my response:

```
{
Response: responseCode: 400,
graphObject: null,
error: {
    HttpStatus: 400,
    errorCode: 190,
    errorType: OAuthException,
    errorMessage: Invalid OAuth access token signature.
}
```

}

Why this happen?

Comment: app-id and secret IS an access token, it is called "App Access Token". not a good idea to use it in an android app though, imho.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea how to do it right?

Comment: authorize the user and use a user token, or use your own server to cache data and do the api calls - or even better, use an extended page token on your server. from your app, call your server instead of the graph api directly.

Comment: So you advice me something like this: facebook - my_server - my_app.
Is it possible to do it like this: facebook - my_app (without user login)?

Comment: of course it´s possible. you should authorize the user for that though, and use his user token. how many users do you expect in your app? with an app token, you may hit api limits even with just a few.

Comment: I want to create app that will get feeds only from one public group for example "Nike" and app do not need any data from user. For example you download app from Google play and read "Nike" feeds without any login. Just open and read. To make that I need a server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111107/discussion-between-zxc123qwe098qqq-and-luschn).

Comment: then use your own server to cache data, or you will most likely hit api limits very fast. also, there is a big difference between "groups" and "pages".